# glusterfs mkfifo permission denied

Tags: glusterfs

I have a glusterfs volume. I can write files to it just fine, but when I am trying to create a pipe, it gives me permission denied.

```
[2017-09-30 15:57:57.148455] E [MSGID: 114031] [client-rpc-fops.c:237:client3_3_mknod_cbk] 0-data-client-2: remote operation failed. Path: /gitlab/data/test/test.socket [Permission denied]
[2017-09-30 15:57:57.148712] W [fuse-bridge.c:471:fuse_entry_cbk] 0-glusterfs-fuse: 354460: MKNOD() /gitlab/data/test/test.socket => -1 (Permission denied)
```

*/etc/fstab:*

```
gluster01:/data /srv/gfs_data glusterfs rw,allow_other,default_permissions,_netdev 0 0
```

---

**EDIT:**

So after disabling and looking at the selinux logs for both bricks, it is blocking it. What context should this be added under?

*SELinux logs*

```
type=AVC msg=audit(1506943186.948:4039): avc:  denied  { create } for  pid=11312 comm="glusteriotwr1" name="test" scontext=system_u:system_r:glusterd_t:s0 tcontext=system_u:object_r:svirt_sandbox_file_t:s0 tclass=fifo_file
type=SYSCALL msg=audit(1506943186.948:4039): arch=c000003e syscall=133 success=no exit=-13 a0=7ff275a6c520 a1=11a4 a2=0 a3=2 items=0 ppid=1 pid=11312 auid=4294967295 uid=0 gid=0 euid=0 suid=0 fsuid=0 egid=0 sgid=0 fsgid=0 tty=(none) ses=4294967295 comm="glusteriotwr1" exe="/usr/sbin/glusterfsd" subj=system_u:system_r:glusterd_t:s0 key=(null)
```

> Solved:
>
> chcon -Rt glusterd_brick_t /bricks/brick1

Comment: Do you have *selinux* enabled?

Comment: @Thomas I do, but I had disabled it to make sure. But I may have only done that on the client and not the server.